# Razor Component is not rendered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I am fairly new to Blazor and tried to use a Razor Component in my Index.cshtml but it wouldn't work. Maybe you can give me a hint where the mistake lies.

The Component (FileUploadComponent.razor) is located in the same folder:
[image]

FileUploadComponent:

```
@inherits ComponentBase

<h3>FileUploadComponent</h3>
Test
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>

    <FileUploadComponent />
</div>
```

Comment: I think your file should be named index.razor.

Comment: Which template did you use to create your project?

Comment: [Polite] Razor Pages..........

Comment: I don't think you should do that.  This isn't MVC.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973, Could you please explain why he shouldn't do that when it is not MVC.

Comment: I dunno.  If I had champagne, I wouldn't go out of my way to pour cooking wine into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was little Oopsie when selecting the wrong Project Template.

When I selected Blazor Webassembly, my code worked and that was what I wanted to have.